I need access to the solana network in my wallet
I was scammed yesterday, because a account on twitter was hacked. Fabiano SOL, that I have been followed for a long time. I did go into a airdrop link, and did click, to see if my wallet was eligble. At that moment I did loose many of my cryptos....
I have still some crypto in my wallet, I have deleted all apps, and disconnected all pages related to my wallet. The problem I´m facing now, is that the SOLANA network in my wallet seems to be open, but I can´t close it, swap any coins or send any coins from my wallet. Is there any chance to get access to the Solana network in my wallet? I have tried your step about rewoke the tokens
